# Unable to load multiple shape classes in UI using --class-picker

Tags: locust

Why does locust load only a single ShapeClass in web UI, when there is more than 1 LoadTestShape class defined in locustfile?

I have defined two LoadTestShape classes in locustfile but only the first class is picked up in UI as seen in this image [Locust UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R377n.png)

Cmd line: locust -f locustfile.py --class-picker

```
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task
from locust import LoadTestShape

class Tasks1(TaskSet):

    @task
    def service(self):
        print("Launching URL")

    @task
    def stop(self):
        self.interrupt()


class FirstUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [Tasks1]

class SecondUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [Tasks1]

class ThirdUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [Tasks1]

class FourthUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [Tasks1]

class FifthUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [Tasks1]




class ramp_up_1min_40users_hold_20min(LoadTestShape):
    stages = [
        {"duration": 60, "users": 40, "spawn_rate": 0.67},
        {"duration": 1200, "users": 40, "spawn_rate": 1},
    ]

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()

        for stage in self.stages:
            if run_time < stage["duration"]:
                try:
                    tick_data = (
                        stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"], stage["user_classes"])
                except:
                    tick_data = (stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"])
                return tick_data

        return None


class ramp_up_20min_40users_hold_5min_ramp_down_5min_1user(LoadTestShape):
    stages = [
        {"duration": 1200, "users": 40, "spawn_rate": 0.034},
        {"duration": 300, "users": 40, "spawn_rate": 1},
        {"duration": 300, "users": 1, "spawn_rate": 0.0325}
    ]

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()

        for stage in self.stages:
            if run_time < stage["duration"]:
                try:
                    tick_data = (
                        stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"], stage["user_classes"])
                except:
                    tick_data = (stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"])
                return tick_data

        return None
```